# How to persist entities that have reference to a shared child entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following scenario: at runtime two "parent" entities are created. Each of them reference one "shared" child entity.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent(Child child)
    {...}
    public Child { get; }
}

Child child = new Child();
Parent mother = new Parent(child)
Parent father = new Parent(child)
```

I would like to be able to save the mother and father instances independently and potentially on a separate thread therefore from within different sessions and transactions.

How do I handle the saving of the Child entity with NH?

OK, 18 views and no comments... I guess I need to add some more clarification.

My mapping defines that Child should be automatically persisted when the Parent is persisted.

What will be happening with the child entity when

```
session.Save(father)
```

is called on one thread and

```
session.Save(mother)
```

on a different thread?

Comment: where do you get the child from? Is it enough to maintain the reference to Child or does each thread alters child?

Comment: The parent does not change the child it only has a reference to it. It is like assigning category to a product, where the category is created on the fly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems from the comment that child is only needed for the reference it is save to use `session.Load<Child>(knownChildId)` in each thread. This will create 2 different Proxies for the same object.

If the child is not yet saved and cascading is set then there could be a potential race condition and either

- save the shared Child before creating the threads which process the parents
- `lock(child)` before `session.Save(father);`
- introduce a unique constraint over the business key in Child and handle DuplicateKeyException on the threads